# Check if new password is the same as confirm new password text boxes

Tags: jquery

I have 2 text boxes. The first one is for new password and the old one is for confirming new password.

```
<script>
    var old = $("#old").val();
    var newPass = $("#new_pass").val();
    var ConfirmPass = $("#confirm_pass").val();

    $("#confirm_pass").keyup(function () {
        if (this.value == newPass) {
            $("#check").toggleClass('fa-times fa-check')
        }

    });
</script>
```

When the user type his new passord then type in confirm password text box I need to change a label from `fa fa-times` into `fa fa-check`.

But when I just put the cursor inside the confirm text box, it's transformed into `fa fa-check` without typing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to move the variables inside the bound event because it always empty on doc ready and for to be sure that the elements are available, wrap the event inside doc ready block.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#confirm_pass").keyup(function(e){

              // now put the code here with all vars

       });


 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are taking all value only once. You should take all values in `keyup` function like following.

```
$("#confirm_pass").keyup(function () {
    var old = $("#old").val();
    var newPass = $("#new_pass").val();

    if (this.value == newPass) {
        $("#check").removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check');
    } else {
        $("#check").removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-times');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using a toggle. You can do this instead:

```
if(this.value == newPass)
{
  $("#check").addClass('fa-check');
  $("#check").removeClass('fa-times');
} else {
  $("#check").removeClass('fa-check');
  $("#check").addClass('fa-times');
}
```

Comment: it didn'r worked. The console shows me that newPass is empty always

Comment: Then move newPass = $("#new_pass").val(); under the keyup function. Make a jsfiddle if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here. Firstly you only retrieve the value of `#new_pass` on load of the page when you should get it right before you do the comparison check. Also, you only set the classes when the check is valid, you also need to cater for someone having valid passwords and then adding/removing a character and making them invalid again. Try this:

```
$("#confirm_pass").keyup(function() {
    var newPass = $("#new_pass").val();
    $("#check").toggleClass('fa-times fa-check', this.value == newPass)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answers, you should really use `$("#confirm_pass").focusout()` instead of `keyup()` because you don't need to check *every time* a new character is typed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#confirm_pass").focusout(function() {
    var old = $("#old").val();
    var newPass = $("#new_pass").val();
    if (this.value === newPass) 
    {
      $("#check").addClass('fa-check');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#check").addClass('fa-times');
    }
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2ypy5yc/2/)

P.S.: This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that yet.